# Yii2 AccessControl

Tags: php, authentication, yii2

I am new in Yii2 and I try to make AccessControl and success
but the problem is after I success for login and redirect to other page
my Identity _attributes always are null.So if I check with `Yii::$app->user->isGuest` the return value is always true

**this is my LoginHandler.php**

```
<?php
namespace app\models;

use Yii;
use yii\base\Model;

/**
 * Login form
 */
class LoginHandler extends Model
{
    public $user_name;
    public $user_password;
    public $rememberMe = true;

    private $_user;


    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
           [['user_name', 'user_password'], 'required'],
            [['user_name', 'user_password'], 'string', 'max' => 100],
            ['user_password','authenticate'],
        ];
    }

    public function authenticate($attribute, $params){
//      return true;
    } 

    public function login()
    {

        if ($this->validate()) {
            return Yii::$app->user->login($this->getUser(), $this->rememberMe ? 3600 * 24 * 30 : 0);            
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    protected function getUser()
    {
        if ($this->_user === null) {
            $this->_user = User::findByUsername($this->user_name);
        }
        return $this->_user;
    }
}
```

**LoginController**

```
    <?php

namespace backend\controllers;
use Yii;
use app\models\user;
use app\models\LoginHandler;

class LoginController extends \yii\web\Controller
{
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        return $this->render('index');
    }

    public function actionSignin(){     
        $user = User::findByUsername('admin');
        $model = new LoginHandler();
        if(Yii::$app->request->post()){
            $data = Yii::$app->request->post();
            $model->attributes = $data;
            if ($model->login()) {
                return $this->redirect(['/user/test']);
            }else{
                die('test');
            }

        }
        return $this->render('login');
    }

}
```

**My User.php as model**

```
    namespace app\models;
    use Yii;

    /**
     * This is the model class for table "user".
     *
     * @property integer $user_id
     * @property string $user_name
     * @property string $user_password
     */
    class User extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord implements \yii\web\IdentityInterface{

        public $id;
        public $authKey;

        /**
         * @inheritdoc
         */
        public static function tableName()
        {
            return 'user';
        }

        /**
         * @inheritdoc
         */
        public function rules()
        {
            return [
                [['user_name', 'user_password'], 'required'],
                [['user_name', 'user_password'], 'string', 'max' => 100]
            ];
        }

        /**
         * @inheritdoc
         */
        public function attributeLabels()
        {
            return [
                'user_id' => 'User ID',
                'user_name' => 'User Name',
                'user_password' => 'User Password',
            ];
        }

        public static function findIdentity($id)
        {
            return static::findOne($id);
        }

        public static function findIdentityByAccessToken($token, $type = null)
        {
            return static::findOne(['access_token' => $token]);
        }

        public function getId()
        {
            return $this->id;
        }

        public function getAuthKey()
        {
            return $this->authKey;
        }

        public function validateAuthKey($authKey)
        {
            return $this->authKey === $authKey;
        }

        public static function findByUsername($username){
            return static::findOne(['user_name' => $username]);
        }
    }
```

**and the last is my configuration main.php**

```
    <?php
$params = array_merge(
    require(__DIR__ . '/../../common/config/params.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/../../common/config/params-local.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/params.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/params-local.php')
);

return [
    'id' => 'app-backend',
    'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
    'controllerNamespace' => 'backend\controllers',
    'bootstrap' => ['log'],
    'modules' => [],
    'components' => [
        'user' => [
            'identityClass' => 'backend\models\User',
            'loginUrl'  => ['login/signin'],
            'enableAutoLogin' => true,
        ],      
        'log' => [
            'traceLevel' => YII_DEBUG ? 3 : 0,
            'targets' => [
                [
                    'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                    'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'errorHandler' => [
            'errorAction' => 'site/error',
        ],
    ],
    'params' => $params,
];
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you have 'backend\models\User' in config when User model defined in app\models namespace?

Comment: Still no working if i change to app\models in my config

Comment: Which template are you using, and where you call `Yii::$app->user->isGuest` ?

Comment: Seems like your session cookie was not configured correctly. Show us your common/config/main.php, common/config/main-local.php & config/main-local.php files as well.

Comment: Two items: 1) What does `get_class_methods(\Yii::$app->user);` return? 2) Recommend following a code style guide for consistency sake. (Perosnal recommendation is the PSR's.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mentioned `AccessControl` in your question. In Yii2 AccessControl is the special behavior class to manage access rules inside controller:

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-filters-accesscontrol.html

and I don't see `AccessControl` in you code.

Anyway.

Most probably the problem is in your implementation of User class. 
Looking at your code I can imagine that the table structure is: `user_id (PK), user_name, user_password`.
If so, then the method `getId()` returns variable 
(`$this->id`) which is never initialized. But this method is used by Yii to store current user in session. In your case it should return `$this->user_id`.

And if you wish to make `remember me` working, you should implement correctly `getAuthKey` and `validateAuthKey` too.

Here is details:
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-security-authentication.html

If this not helps, then show your table structure and code of view which pass authentication data to `LoginController`

Answer (score 0):

It looks you should check for

```
Yii::$app->user->identity
```